# How to prevent hackers from uploading files into ftp server

Tags: asp.net, hacking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My server's been hacked EMERGENCY](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency)

I have been design an asp.net site with .net framework 3.5 all thing is good until my site hacked suddenly it says a chines group and some other text by picture jpg they put files into the ftp server I delete them and they put them again I change all password and they do it again I think they are some script programmer and I can do nothing by deleting method, please help me.

Comment: Do you have an uplaod form on your website?

Comment: You shouldn't be running an FTP server in this day and age.

Comment: What is a solution I can't stop my working

Comment: Joe: What's wrong with FTP? It's still good for fileservers that allow anonymous access.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's pretty clear that you don't have the technical skills to be able to complete this job -- it's a difficult problem, with [many potential areas of exploration and avenues of attack that need to be secured](http://www.anchor.com.au/blog/2009/11/securing-your-codez-from-the-wily-exploit-injectors/).  I would recommend engaging the services of an experienced systems administrator to investigate these options, cleanup the infection, and deploy the appropriate safeguards to prevent it happening again.

Answer (score 0):

They replaced default.aspx instead of my default.aspx I have upload or script uploading I don't know exactly whay they are doing some complex operation.

Answer (score 0):

As a developer, you should know if your app is secure or not. In the other hand, even if you have the most perfect and protected app, if there is a huge hole at system level, your programming skills won't worth too much and you'll be cracked anyway. Just hire a sysadmin so your system can be properly secured.

Answer (score -1):

Yes womble I know I am developer not system administrator but I don't know where is the hole they attack again and again I think it is more complicated that you can explain but I want to know about how to prevent I know how to pay for system administrator and how to find him I want to know how they attack I had upload by some script on the ftp server by Injection or not some else method ?

Comment: Please add these sort of things as comments or amend your question, they are not answers.